# Outer join in oracle with ANSI standard

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
select ...
from A left outer join B on (B.x=A.x)
left outer join C on (C.y=A.y)
```

want to add one additional join of table D with table C with a condition D.z=C.z

```
select ...
from A left outer join B on (B.x=A.x)
left outer join C on (C.y=A.y), D inner join C on (D.z=C.z)
```

however, query does not work after adding this part " , D inner join C on (D.z=C.z) ".

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

You should just add `left outer join D on (D.z=C.z)`. If you use INNER JOIN you remove rows from A and B which not connected with C and D

```
select ...
from A left outer join B on (B.x=A.x)
left outer join C on (C.y=A.y)
left outer join D on (D.z=C.z)
```

Comment: Earlier it was like this..
select ....
from A, B, C, D
where B.x=A.x(+) and
C.y=A.y(+) and
C.z=D.z

It does not work as it says B and C should be joined before. S, applied ANSI standard to the outer joins and it worked well. However, when I m adding last condition as ANSI standard, it does not work.

Comment: the logic works fine. Thanks. However, could you explain that in the last line, we r joining A with D. correct? But I wanted the join between C and D. Will this above give the same result ?

Comment: Yes but C already joined with A with the second join so A->C->D

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is not just table `C` but the result of an inner join between `C` and `D` that you want to outer-join to table `A`.

If that is so, then [@valex's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044122/297408) is an alternative but equivalent way to represent that logic.

In some SQL products the syntax would allow you to write out the logic exactly as intended:

```
…
FROM
  A
  LEFT JOIN B ON (B.x=A.x)
  LEFT JOIN
    C
    INNER JOIN D ON (D.z=C.z)
  ON (C.y=A.y)
```

Oracle doesn't support such syntax. But you could rewrite the query like this in order to make the syntax more closely reflect the intended logic:

```
…
FROM
  C
  INNER JOIN D ON (D.z=C.z)
  RIGHT JOIN A ON (C.y=A.y)
  LEFT  JOIN B ON (B.x=A.x)
```

Now it is clear that `C` and `D` are supposed to be inner-joined and their result should be outer-joined to `A` (`A` being on the outer side of the join, which is the right side this time, hence `RIGHT JOIN`), followed by an outer join of `B` to `A`.

Still, as I said, @valex's is an equivalent suggestion that should produce the same results.